# Get 401 unauthorized web exception when consuming rest json api in c#

Tags: c#, json, rest

i have bin trying to consume a rest json api with a get request but i always 401 unauthorized exception. According to the owners of the web service they are using http basic authentication. I have tried the credentials by logging in through chrome so they are working fine.

```
var synCClient = new WebClient();
synCClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
var content = synCClient.DownloadString(url);
```

I have also tried this solution which i found in kowalczyks blog

```
string authInfo = userName + ":" + passWord;
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic" + authInfo;
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
                                     ^
```

You seem to have missed space after "Basic"

Comment: Could be it, let me get it a try

Comment: That was not the case, still looking for an answer