# c# - System.Web.Exception 401 while posting data

Tags: c#, post, system.web

My request method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The formal method to use HTTPWebRequests.
    /// I got the headers out of Fiddler. I highly recommend this tool to follow HTTPWebRequests.
    /// Some Headers are unnecessary but i will use them for a natural-looking HTTPWebRequests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inpUrl">URL of the HTTPWebRequest.</param>
    /// <param name="inpMethod">Method of the HTTPWebRequest.
    /// Example: "POST", "GET", "PUT",...</param>
    /// <param name="inpReferer">The Referer of the URL. Sometimes its needed.</param>
    /// <param name="inpHost">The Host of the request.</param>
    /// <param name="inpAccept">Accept format of the request.</param>
    /// <param name="inpNvc">Data which will be wrote if you will do a "Post".</param>
    /// <param name="inpXml">If Ajax, then this is required.</param>
    /// <param name="autoRedirect">Auto-Redirect.</param>
    /// <returns>A HttpWebResponse of the request.</returns>
    private HttpWebResponse Request(string inpUrl, string inpMethod, string inpReferer, string inpHost, string inpAccept, NameValueCollection inpNvc, bool inpXml, bool autoRedirect)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(inpUrl);
        request.Accept = inpAccept;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36";
        request.Timeout = 20000;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = autoRedirect;
        request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        request.Method = inpMethod;
        //Volatile variables

        if (inpHost != "")
        {
            request.Host = inpHost;
        }

        if (inpReferer != "")
        {
            request.Referer = inpReferer;
        }
        if (inpXml)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            request.Headers.Add("X-Prototype-Version", "1.7");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        }

        if (inpMethod != "POST") return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        var dataString = (inpNvc == null ? null : string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(inpNvc.AllKeys, key =>
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) +"=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inpNvc[key])
            )));
        if (dataString == null) return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        var dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }
```

I was using normally but today.It is throwing me errors when i tried to post new order to a shop website.I have logged on at website with program after that i am adding cookies to a container,but program throwing System.Web.Exception 401 //Authorization error.

I'm trying to request for https://backpack.tf/classifieds/sell/4219201808
Html form = http://pastebin.com/5xLp2jSU
My post order method =

```
    public void PostOrder(string inpUrl, string metal, int key, string message, bool tradeOffer, bool buyOut, string tradeOfferUrl)
    {
        var data = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"user-id", _userId},
            {"currencies[metal]", metal},
            {"currencies[keys]", key.ToString()},
            {"details", message}
        };
        if (tradeOffer)
        {
            if (tradeOfferUrl != string.Empty)
            {
                data.Add("offers", "1");
                data.Add("tradeoffers_url", tradeOfferUrl);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("offers", "0");
            data.Add("tradeoffers_url", "");
        }
        data.Add("buyout", buyOut ? "1" : "0");
        const string accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        const string referer = "http://backpack.tf/classifieds/buy/Strange/Rust%20Botkiller%20Scattergun%20Mk.I/Tradable/Craftable";
        const string host = "backpack.tf";
        using (var httpResponse = Request(inpUrl, "POST", referer, host, accept, data, false, false))
        {
            _cookies.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
        }
    }
```

My login method

```
public void DoLogin(string inpSteamUserName, string inpSteamPassword, string inpSharedSecret = "")
    {
        _cookiePath += inpSteamUserName + ".auth";
        var responseString = GetIndex();
        SetUserId(responseString);
        var location = PostLogin();
        SetOpenIdParams(location);
        // Now do Steam Login.
        dynamic steamResult = DoSteamLogin(inpSteamUserName, inpSteamPassword, inpSharedSecret);
        if (steamResult == null) return;
        PostTransfer(steamResult.transfer_parameters.steamid.ToString(),
            steamResult.transfer_parameters.token.ToString(),
            steamResult.transfer_parameters.auth.ToString(),
            steamResult.transfer_parameters.remember_login.ToString(),
            steamResult.transfer_parameters.token_secure.ToString());
        location = OpenIdLogin();
        location = GetBackpackCookies(location);
        if (location == "/" || location == "https://backpack.tf/")
        {
            // Verify Cookies.
            const string url = "https://backpack.tf/";
            const string method = "GET";
            const string host = "backpack.tf";
            const string accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            FetchRequest(url, method, "", host, accept, null, false, true);
        }
        Log.Success("Bot logged in to backpack.tf");
```

and

```
 private dynamic DoSteamLogin(string username, string password, string inpSharedSecret)
    {
        dynamic returnObject;
        var data = new NameValueCollection { { "username", username } };
        const string accept = "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*";
        const string referer = "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fbackpack.tf%2Flogin&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fbackpack.tf&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select";
        const string host = "steamcommunity.com";
        var response = FetchRequest("https://steamcommunity.com/login/getrsakey", "POST", referer, host, accept,
            data, true, false);
        var rsaJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetRsaKeyBackPack>(response);

        // Validate
        if (!rsaJson.Success)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //RSA Encryption
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters
        {
            Exponent = HexToByte(rsaJson.PublickeyExp),
            Modulus = HexToByte(rsaJson.PublickeyMod)
        };

        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

        var bytePassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        var encodedPassword = rsa.Encrypt(bytePassword, false);
        var encryptedBase64Password = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedPassword);

        SteamResultBackPack loginJson = null;
        CookieCollection cookieCollection;
        var steamGuardText = "";
        var steamGuardId = "";
        do
        {
            Log.Success("SteamWeb: Logging In...");

            var captcha = loginJson != null && loginJson.CaptchaNeeded;
            var steamGuard = loginJson != null && loginJson.EmailauthNeeded;

            var time = Uri.EscapeDataString(rsaJson.Timestamp);
            var capGid = "-1";
            if (loginJson != null)
            {
                capGid = Uri.EscapeDataString(loginJson.CaptchaGid);
            }
            data = new NameValueCollection { { "password", encryptedBase64Password }, { "username", username } };

            // Captcha
            var capText = "";
            if (captcha)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SteamWeb: Captcha is needed.");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://steamcommunity.com/public/captcha.php?gid=" + loginJson.CaptchaGid);
                Console.WriteLine("SteamWeb: Type the captcha:");
                capText = Uri.EscapeDataString(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            data.Add("captchagid", captcha ? capGid : "");
            data.Add("captcha_text", captcha ? capText : "");
            if (inpSharedSecret != "")
            {
                var twoFactorGenerator = new SteamTwoFactorGenerator
                {
                    SharedSecret = inpSharedSecret
                };
                data.Add("twofactorcode", twoFactorGenerator.GenerateSteamGuardCodeForTime());
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add("twofactorcode", "");
            }

            data.Add("remember_login", "false");

            // Captcha end

            // SteamGuard
            if (steamGuard)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SteamWeb: SteamGuard is needed.");
                Console.WriteLine("SteamWeb: Type the code:");
                steamGuardText = Uri.EscapeDataString(Console.ReadLine());
                steamGuardId = loginJson.Emailsteamid;
                data.Add("loginfriendlyname", "machine1");
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add("loginfriendlyname", inpSharedSecret);
            }

            data.Add("emailauth", steamGuardText);
            data.Add("Emailsteamid", steamGuardId);
            data.Add("donotcache", "1440170894227");

            // SteamGuard end

            data.Add("rsatimestamp", time);

            using (var webResponse = Request("https://steamcommunity.com/login/dologin/", "POST", referer, host, accept, data, true, false))
            {
                // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    returnObject = JObject.Parse(json);
                    loginJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SteamResultBackPack>(json);
                    cookieCollection = webResponse.Cookies;
                }
            }
        } while (loginJson.CaptchaNeeded || loginJson.EmailauthNeeded);


        if (loginJson.Success)
        {
            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieCollection)
            {
                _cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            return returnObject;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SteamWeb Error: " + loginJson.Message);
        return null;
    }
```

My request method throwing errors at only posting new order.

Fixed:It source is login method.

Comment: do you have code or documentation for requested URL?

Comment: Go into webbrowser history and delete all cookies.  Close all IE windows then try again.  if that doesn't work then open manually an IE and try request manually.  Then try with application.

Comment: @Robert I have explain better now.

Comment: @jdweng I tried but still same.

Comment: @Muratsirma where is your Authorization logic?

Comment: @Robert i added my login methots.

Comment: Can you manually log into database?  An admin may have logins locked out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get 401 unauthorized web exception when consuming rest json api in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678165/get-401-unauthorized-web-exception-when-consuming-rest-json-api-in-c-sharp)